# React navigate after login with keycloak

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

Using expo-keycloak-auth

https://www.npmjs.com/package/expo-keycloak-auth

I am trying to add the login to an existing screen. I am able to login successfully. I want the user to be able to click a button to navigate to the new screen. this is the code (almost identical to the example on github)

```
export const Auth = () => {
 
  const {
    ready, // If the discovery is already fetched and ready to prompt authentication flow
    login, // The login function - opens the browser
    isLoggedIn, // Helper boolean to use e.g. in your components down the tree
    token, // Access token, if available
    logout, // The logout function - Logs the user out
  } = useKeycloak();
  if (!ready) return <ActivityIndicator />;

  if (!isLoggedIn)
    
    return (
      <View  style={styles.ViewRr}>

<ButtonSolid style={{ fontSize: 20, marginTop: 24 }} onPress={login} title="Login" title={'Log in'}   />
     </View>
    );

  return (
    <View style={{ margin: 24 }}>
      <Text  style={{ fontSize: 17, marginBottom: 24 }}>Successfully Logged in!</Text>
      <TextInput value={token}></TextInput>
      <Text></Text>
      <ButtonSolid  style={{ fontSize: 20, marginBottom: 24 }}
         onPress={() => {
          try {
            navigation.navigation(‘MainNav’, { screen: ‘Startup });
          } catch (err) {
            console.error(err);
          }
        }}
        style={[
          styles.ButtonSolidIM,
          { backgroundColor: "#000" },
        ]}
        title={'Log In'}
            title={'Continue'}
          />
      <Button onPress={logout} title={"Logout"} style={{ marginTop: 24 }} />
    </View>
  );
};
```

I am adding that to my screen like so

```
const LoginScreen = props => {
   
  const { navigation } = props;

 return (
    <ScreenContainer hasSafeArea={true} scrollable={true}>
      <KeycloakProvider {...keycloakConfiguration}>
    <Auth/>
      </KeycloakProvider>
    </ScreenContainer>
```

the problem is that navigation is not available in the Auth() function. is there a way to pass it in or am I doing this completely wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pass navigation from LoginScreen as prop to Auth component:

```
const Auth = (props) => {

     props.navigation...
  }
```

and in LoginScreen:

```
...
<Auth navigation={navigation} />
...
```

Comment: I tried to do that like <Auth> nav={navigation} </Auth> but it gives me an error navigation is not function of nav

Comment: Updated answer. Have you done it like that?

Comment: yeah, seems I am getting the object but I still get the error navigate is not a function. I dumped the variable passed. Seems like its there
"props": Object {
    "getState": [Function anonymous],
    "goBack": [Function anonymous],
    "navigate": [Function anonymous],

Comment: seems like it was just I was accessing the method incorrectly thanks